# Annotation values in for loop

Tags: objective-c

```
for(AnnotationView* annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
{
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}
```

whether this loop stores latitude and longitude for its first annotation or last annotation  or all annotations? Please do clarify me...

Comment: can you please elaborate what you want to ask

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is "the loop which i've given will find the number of annotations and finds the topleft and bottomright's latitude and logitude for each annotation. When the for loop executes, the variables topleftcoord.longitude, topleftcoord.latitude, bottomrightcoord.longitude, bottomrightcoord.latitude is replaced by each annotation's latitude and longitude values. Then what will be the result of final topleft and bottomright coordinates?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes through all of the elements in `annotations` and "creates" an annotation that represents the points that make a box around all of the existing annotations.

So kind of like this:

Assume all of your annotations in your array are the green ones. The for-loop basically would go through and leave `topLeftCoord`'s lat and long values equivelent to the top left point (the red one) and `bottomRightCoord`'s lat and long values equal to the bottom right point (the other red one).

[image: Visual Mapping]

Comment: Thank you ji...I got clarified.